# Is there a required size of data set for LDA to work in python?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to apply LDA on Stack overflow posts for a project. My corpus has about 650 post of interest and I was wondering if the size of the corpus would hinder the functioning of the LDA later on especially when I have to specify the K value?

I have not applied LDA before, therefore some hints on this would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work. What happens when you try it? Are the results useful according to your goals with those 650 posts?

Comment: Well, that is what I would like to understand before I run the model since I read that the more data provided to LDA; the better the results get. This is a bit tricky in stack overflow posts since the post and answers could possibly talk about two topics in one post. I was wondering if I was at a disadvantage here due to a small corpus. I am still in the preprocessing and dataset creatin phase.

Comment: Run LDA with K=2 topics, see if you're happy with the result, and slowly increase K. At some point you will feel that K is "too big" because similar documents wind up in different topics too often.

Comment: Running LDA on such a tiny number of documents takes very little time, and knowing whether the results are useful will be very specific to your goals: only you can look at the results and say, "that's what I was hoping for", or "this is bad, maybe I need more data, more tuning, or other techniques". There's no way, beforehand, with the tiny info in your question, to issue much judgement or advice. Try it, and if the results disapppoint, ask a more specific question.

Comment: Okay, I will proceed with these hints, Thanks!